# Create new sql table based on a query from another table MariaDb

Tags: mysql, mariadb, stored-procedures

Just to preface this I am very much a noob when it comes to dbs.

As the title states I want to create a new table based on query I do on an already existing table. At first I thought a view would be a good idea since I am not creating new data but removing redundant rows. The issue is the query takes around ~5min to do and that's way too slow, so I figured instead of creating a view why not use the query to create a new table that is populated once a day.

Would the smart move be to make a [Scheduled Event](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/events/) that runs the query a day and generate the table that way?

I am using Mariadb with HeidiSQL as the IDE

Thank you in advance for all help

Comment: I'd say the smart move would be to optimize your query so that it doesn't take five minutes to complete. If you decide to follow that route, consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `VIEWs` are syntactic sugar, not a way to speed up anything.
- This will create a new table from a select:

  ```
    CREATE TABLE foo
        SELECT ....;
  ```
- This creates a `TEMPORARY` table that will go away when you disconnect:

  ```
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo
        SELECT ....;
  ```
- To rebuild the table daily, this will repopulate it:

  ```
    TRUNCATE TABLE foo;
    INSERT INTO foo
        SELECT ....;
  ```
- The Truncate technique leaves the table empty for 5 minutes.  If that is not acceptable, there is a workaround.
- If the source table is a "data warehouse", then building and maintaining a "summary table" will cut the "5 minutes" down significantly.

Which of those would you like to discuss further?

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment, The truncate table will work for me, and what do you mean by data warehouse?

Comment: @mike_gundy123 - Lots of rows coming in; many queries summarize the things like "number of items sold and the revenue from that -- for a specified day or week or whatever".

Comment: Na, that's not the case. My table is only being updated once a day

Comment: Also for the truncate table option I just need to create the table once (with all the indexes chosen out) and I can constantly just truncate and add into it no problem?

Comment: @mike_gundy123 - See also http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#optimal_reload_of_a_table